# How to create new json object from exiting one?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create new json object from exiting one, because if I create from

```
var person1= { First Name: 'John',
  Last Name: 'Smith',
  age: 54,
  dateofbirth: '31-08-68',
 }
var person2=person1;
delete person2.age
```

This will also delete age from the person1, I don't want to delete age from person1, but person2. Because I need to initialize other person also. So How I create new json object from exiting object .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clone the object. The quick way is

```
var person2=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person1));
```